# Getting "Access Denied" while downloading an object

Tags: vbscript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to download a svn client by running a batch script. For that I am using this piece of VBS which I call from the batch file. Now this code works because I have successfully downloaded some files but when I am trying to download [this file](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/tortoisesvn/1.7.11/Application/TortoiseSVN-1.7.11.23600-x64-svn-1.7.8.msi?r=&ts=1392213823&use_mirror=iweb) from sourceforge.net I am getting a access denied error message after `send()`. Any insight on why this is happening and can be avoided will be helpful.

```
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
objXMLHTTP.send()
do until objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 :  wscript.sleep(1000) :  loop 

If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
  Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  objADOStream.Open
  objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

  objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
  objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start

  Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
  Set objFSO = Nothing

  objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
  objADOStream.Close
  Set objADOStream = Nothing
End if

Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
```

Comment: Which line exactly is raising the error? And what is the exact error message, including the error number? Also note that `send` already waits for the request to complete, since you set the 3rd parameter to `False`, so the loop isn't required. Even worse, it becomes an infinite loop if the request should return with any status except 200.

Comment: Error : Access is denied. Code : 80070005 Source: msxml3.dll
Well ok. But it didnt go to an infinite loop i guess because the error came before that. THe line no is of send().

Answer (score 2):

You're getting access denied because you're trying to download a file from a URL that is redirecting you.  If you try to download a file directly, you'll find you won't get the error.

You should use the latest version..

```
Set objXMLHTTP= CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
```

However using..

```
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
```

..is ok for now.

If you were to add sourceforge.com to your trusted sites in IE, go into IE Options->Security, select Trusted sites go into the Custom Level, change "Access data sources across domains" to Enable, that should let you get beyond that Access Denied error.

Comment: ok! Isn't there any other way to download a file from such a link other than changing the IE options ? Actually the batch will run on different computers to which i will not have access to change the ie settings

Comment: You could still use VBScript, however you could use, let's say, wget.exe and then just execute wget.exe.  Or, download that file from SourceForge, move it to a local web server, and download it directly via the script you already have.